# Incorrect date in TIMESTAMP like DD_MM_YYYY_HH_MI_SS

Tags: javascript, variables, date, timestamp

Colls, I have a code which should create a sToday variable which returns timestamp like “DD_MM_YYYY_HH_MI_SS”:

```
var today = new Date();

var CurrentDay = today.getDay();
var CurrentMonth = today.getMonth();
var CurrentHours = today.getHours();
var CurrentMin = today.getMinutes();
var CurrentSec = today.getSeconds();

if (CurrentDay < 10)
   sToday = "0"+today.getDay().toString();
else 
   sToday = today.getDay().toString();

if(CurrentMonth<10)
  sToday += "_0"+today.getMonth().toString();
else 
  sToday += "_"+today.getMonth().toString();

sToday += "_"+today.getYear().toString();

if (CurrentHours<10)
  sToday += "_0"+today.getHours().toString();
else 
  sToday += "_"+today.getHours().toString();

if (CurrentMin<10)  
  sToday += "_0"+today.getMinutes().toString();
else 
  sToday += "_"+today.getMinutes().toString();

if (CurrentSec<10)
sToday += "_0"+today.getSeconds().toString();
else
sToday += "_"+today.getSeconds().toString();
```

But when I run it 13.04.2012 20:20:14 (my pc time) then I receive  05_03_2012_20_20_14 .
How to fix this and receive 13_04_2012_20_20_14 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDate` returns the date 1-31. `getDay` returns the day of the week 0-6, with 0 being Sunday.
`getMonth` returns the month 0-11, so you need to add 1 to that value.

Instead of printing Date, Month, right now, you're printing Day, Month - 1.

Alter your code to this:

```
if (CurrentDay < 10)
   sToday = "0"+today.getDate().toString();
else 
   sToday = today.getDate().toString();

if(CurrentMonth<10)
  sToday += "_0"+ (today.getMonth() + 1).toString();
else 
  sToday += "_"+(today.getMonth() + 1).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday,...) . You want to use [`.getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) instead.

```
function tw(n){
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') +  n.toString();
}

var today = new Date();
var sToday = (tw(today.getDate()) + '_' + tw(today.getMonth()+1) + '_' +
             today.getYear().toString() +  '_' + tw(today.getHours()) +
             '_' + tw(today.getMinutes()) + '_' + tw(today.getSeconds()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .getDate for the day and add 1 to the month (months are zero-based, so January is 0, February is 1 and so on...)